# Make multiple smaller weapon animation clips out of big default action for use in Unity game engine

Tags: animation, unity, actions

I made weapon animation for mobile game. I have one big animation that includes all states of weapon ( idle, hipFire, reload, wield, remove, aimedFire, run)
I want to make separate animation clips out of this big one, and then delete it, so i would endup with 7 short animation clips when impotred in Unity. 
I wached all vids and tuts on youtube but didn`t find one that adresses similar task.
Thanks in advance for any help!
There`s other thing too.
I somehow  have two actions in the file.[image] One that has all keyframes in it. And other without any keyframes, it attached to weapon mesh. I dont know how to get rid of it. 
[image]
Hope there is solution for my trouble)
Thanks for help guys!!!

[Edit]
i found the way to delete actions from action editor! There is no need to choose Orphan Data in Outliner. You choose All Scenes.You type exact name of action you want to delete. All it`s stuff will appear in Outliner than you right click on it and choose "delete". [image]
So deleting stubborn actions is solved!)
I found this way here [Delete actions from action editor?](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/5vmy20/delete_actions_from_action_editor/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest in my opinion way to do that is to bake the animation fragments to new actions, separate for each desired state. To do that, use Action>Bake Action which you find in left tab (appears and disappears after pressing "T"). You'll achieve desired bake length by restricting animation time on the timeline to each state duration. After baking just move keyframes of created this way new action to the timeline beginning and voila.
You can get rid of unnecessary action by removing it from the mesh (or whatever else it's assigned to) in Action Editor (click on X icon on the right from the action name) and then choose Orphan Data in Outliner Search menu and click on Purge All. (this way you will get rid of all actions, textures, materials etc. that have no user permanently, so be careful to check everything first).

Comment: i found the way to delete actions from action editor!

Comment: Thanks for hints!  Action i wanted to delete didn`t have fake users it had few users and didn`t have any keyframes. I foun the way to get rid of it after 4 days of seaching for answers)

Comment: Baking new shorter  actions from big one i have is the way i`ll try. Thanks again for this hint. Do you know of any articles or tutors i could use about this topic?

Comment: Not really, I was learning this a long time ago. I think that you'll find plenty by typing "baking animation in Blender" in Google.